# Request for Advice on Study Material

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, set-theory

I want to learn number theory from the basics, but being in the tenth grade, I am not sure if I would understand everything. Therefore, I need some help regarding what is it that I must read through to get a nice understanding of number theory. A bit of set theory as a topic to learn in the study material alongside the number theory part will also be great (since I am neither a good beginner nor an expert at set theory ).

Currently, I have the lecture notes and exercise questions from Professor Abhinav Kumar's MIT spring lecture series (I got it from OCW), but they are all notes, so I may not be able to grasp the whole picture. It would be great if you suggest me the best book that I can learn from.

Comment: https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas Cochy "The elementary introduction to number theory". The best book I have ever seen :D

Comment: @KNPC is it so ? I have never seen it... does it have chapters pertaining to studying set theory as well ?

Comment: No, this book doesn't have the introduction to set theory. For this topic you need to find another book)